# Zip files in C# in batches

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Zip Archive method to zip files in a folder. However, there is a requirement to read max 10 files from a folder at a particular time and zip it. If there are a large number of files say 100, then 10 zip folders need to be created using C#.

How do I achieve this?
I have tried this in Windows forms -

```
private void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  

    string FolderPathToZip = txtFolderPath.Text.Trim();  
    //To create unique file name with date and time with nanoseconds.  
    string ZipFileName = "D:\\backup\\bak-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmssfffff") + ".zip";  
    try {  
        //To check whether D:\Backup folder exists or not.  
        //If not exists this will create a BACKUP folder.  
        if (Directory.Exists("D:\\backup")) {} else {  
            Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\backup");  
        }  
        //TO create a zip file.  
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(FolderPathToZip, ZipFileName);  
    } catch (Exception) {  
        //If system throw any exception message box will display "SOME ERROR"  
        MessageBox.Show("Some Error");  
    }  
    //Display successfully created message to the user.  
    MessageBox.Show("Zip Filename : " + ZipFileName + " Created Successfully");  
}
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything, so you don't have coding problem, only one of effort. Please take the time to read the help on asking a question

Comment: This is possible in C hashtag. Please can you show us what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psuedo Code:

1. Create a DirectoryInfo object for the Path where files exists
2. Use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() to get the list of all files (*current)
3. In a loop (i=0; 10*i<fileList.Count; i++) do the following

   - subset = fileList.Skip(10 * i).Take(10);
   - Loop over this subset and create the Zip Archive

Be Happy :)